# SSRS CreateSubscription - setting Locale

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

We have a custom built application, based on silverlight, which manages our report subscriptions. The problem is that whenever you add a new subscription, it sets the Locale value in the Subscriptions table to 'en-US'.

When you create subscriptions directly in Report Manager, the value in the Locale field is determined by your browser language settings (this is exactly what we want to achieve).

We can't find a way to set the Locale field before we call the CreateSubscription method as it doesn't seem to accept the Locale parameter and it defaults to en-US (which I believe is a server setting).

Do you know of any way to set Locale when creating subscriptions in SSRS?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see there is no way to do this; I've been using the service via C#.

I decided upon a solution of obtaining the language/locale of the report via the service, and then making the changes directly in the ReportServer database, as an `UPDATE` statement on the SubscriptionID.

To get the language/locale of the report I use something like:

```
private static void Main()
{
    ReportingService2010 service = new ReportingService2010();

    service.Url = "URL of service";
    service.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

    string reportItemPath = "Path of report";

    string language = GetReportPropertyValue(service, reportItemPath, "Language", "en-GB");

    // Create the subscription, then update the database using the returned SubscriptionID.
}

private static string GetReportPropertyValue(ReportingService2010 service, string itemPath, string propertyName, string defaultValue)
{
    Property[] properties = service.GetProperties(itemPath, null);

    if (properties.Any(p => p.Name == propertyName))
        return properties.First(p => p.Name == propertyName).Value;
    else
        return defaultValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it via the SOAP API yet, but shouldn't it be possible to set the Accept-Language header?
I'm doing this when rendering reports in different languages. The language of each report is set to `=User!Language`.
When using WCF to access the reporting service, you can do (example as VB.NET)

```
Using oReportingService As New ReportingService2010SoapClient
    oReportingService.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation

    Using oScope As OperationContextScope = New OperationContextScope(oReportingService.InnerChannel)
      If i_oSubscription.Language IsNot Nothing Then
        ' Accept-Language
        Dim oHttpRequestProperty As New HttpRequestMessageProperty
        oHttpRequestProperty.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, i_oSubscription.Language)
        OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name) = oHttpRequestProperty
      End If

      oReportingService.CreateSubscription(New ReportingService2010.TrustedUserHeader(), i_oSubscription.Path, oExtensionSettings, i_oSubscription.Description, "TimedSubscription", sMatchData, lstParameters.ToArray(), sSubscriptionId)

      Return sSubscriptionId
    End Using
  End Using
```

Edit: This is the way I'm doing it myself and it seems to work :)

`i_oSubscription` is just a simple container with properties like `Description`

Note: this seems to work for the most part. However, the "Days" field in a MonthlyRecurrence is to be formatted locale-dependent (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16011008/ssrs-monthlyrecurrence-formatting-for-different-languages)

Comment: P.S: Be wary of formatting. Apparently "Days" for a MonthlyRecurrence must be formatted with commas for "en-US" and with semicolon for "de-DE".

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've just tried your approach, however it didn't work. The Locale value in the Subscription table is still set to 'en'-US' for new subscriptions. Are you using this code for subscriptions or just for rendering reports? As we're only having problems with the first part, we're able to render reports in any language we want simply by specifying UserLocale in the asp.net page which hosts reports.

Comment: @tomsky I'm using the same style for rendering reports as well as creating subscriptions. PS I expanded the code example to show more of the relevant code for this. The Locale value is then set accordingly.

Comment: I tried this again with different languages ("en-GB", "de-DE") but none of those worked and all the values in the Subscriptions.Locale column are "en-US".

Comment: @tomsky which SQL Server version are you using? I'm running this with 2008 R2, access is via a WCF client, everything running under .NET 4.0. For me, the locale column gets set just fine (tested with `en-US`, `de-AT`, `de-CH` and `en-GB`)

Comment: We're also using SQL Server 2008 R2 and .NET 4.0. The app is built in silverlight, so I wonder if that could be a problem (in order to render reports we use asp.net page and we're able to set Locale correctly for rendering).